# References on $\text{Rep}(H)$ is a braided tensor category

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, hopf-algebras

There is the statement:

> Let $H$ be a Hopf algebra, then $\text{Rep}(H)$ is a braided tensor category.

Does anybody know some references on this? Is it covered in Kassel's 'Quantum Groups'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct statement is

> Let $H$ be a quasi-triangular Hopf-algebra, then $\text{Rep}(H)$ is a braided monoidal category.

This statement is covered in Kassel, see proposition XIII 1.4 in his chapter on braided categories. The literal statement is stronger:

> Let $H$ be a bialgebra. Then $\text{Rep}(H)$ is braided if an only if $H$ is a braided algebra (also called a quasi-triangular structure).

The easiest braiding obviously is a flip map. Notice that if $H$ is a cocommutative Hopf-algebra (i.e. the quasi-triangular structure is trivial), then $\text{Rep}(H)$ is trivially braided.

Comment: So my statement is wrong but if I add cocommutatice it will become right?

Comment: With cocommutativity the braiding will be the flip map. There are also Hopf algebras that do not admit a quasi-triangular structure, their module categories don't admit a braiding. (The flip map will fail as it will not be a module map).

Comment: Does it change anything if I consider a Hopf algebra over a field? But anyway Rep(H) is monoidal in every case? H is again a Hopf algebra here.

Comment: I implicitly assumed you were considering finite dimensional Hopf algebras over a field (of characteristic zero). Once you start considering Hopf algebras over rings, I am not so sure how much of the Hopf algebra you can recover from it's category of representations.

Comment: Maybe one last question: Let H be a Hopf algebra over a field and H' a quasi-Hopf algebra over a field. What can I say about the categories Rep(H) and Rep(H')? Are there monoidal or braided?

Comment: Those categories are always monoidal and they are braided if $H$ and $H'$ admit quasi-triangular structures.

Comment: When there is a descent answer at a question and furtthermore the answerer displays willingness to further respond (at the comments) in any further question/requirement for clarification,  set by the OP (or other users), i think it should be fair for the answer to be upvoted. I cannot understand why the OP should not -at the very least- provide the least of credit: a single upvote. In any case, +1 from me.

Comment: @KonKan: Returned the favor, perhaps, I should have explained how the quasi-triangular structure induces the braiding as you did.

Answer (score 1):

The following is supplementary to the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2555323/195021) provided by user Mathematician 42 (in the sense that it provides an alternative citation apart from Kassel's book already mentioned above and some further remarks):

> **Theorem:** Let $B$ a bialgebra. Then
>
> 1. $B$ is quasitriangular $\Leftrightarrow$ the category ${}_{B}\mathcal{M}$ of left $B$-modules, is a braided monoidal category.
> 2. $B$ is coquasitriangular $\Leftrightarrow$ the category $\mathcal{M}^{B}$ of right $B$-comodules, is a braided monoidal category.
>
> Moreover, $B$ is triangular (resp. cotriangular) $\Leftrightarrow$ ${}_{B}\mathcal{M}$ (resp. $\mathcal{M}^{B}$) is symmetric monoidal.

A proof of the above theorem can be found at Montgomery's book "Hopf algebras and their actions on rings", ch. 10, p. 199-201, Theorem 10.4.2. (a detailed discussion on the conceptual and formal origins of this idea and some of its descendants is also included, see p.201-203).

What essentially happens here is that given the $R$-matrix $R=\sum R^{(1)}\otimes R^{(2)}$ then the the family of $H$-module isomorphisms $\psi_{V,W}:V\otimes W\rightarrow W\otimes V$ given explicitly by $\psi_{V,W}(x\otimes y)=\sum R^{(2)}\cdot y\otimes R^{(1)}\cdot x$ constitutes a braiding.   (If you are interested in further details for the special case where the original hopf algebra is a group hopf algebra, see also p.80-81 of [this article](http://www.mdpi.com/2075-1680/1/1/74) and the references therein).
(In the special case where the original hopf algebra is trivially quasitriangular (i.e. cocommutative) then the braided monoidal category is actually a symmetric monoidal category and the braiding degenerates into the usual flip map, as has already been mentioned both in the comments and in Mathematician 42's answer as well).

Comment: Thank you! How does the notion of a quasi-bialgebra fits into this equivalentes?

Comment: @GIng: i am not really sure about this. Maybe it would be a good idea to ask it as a separate question.